# Waiting for cache cleaning before reading core_config_data in Magento 2 (Asyncronous)

Tags: magento2, database, configuration

I have a scenario where I save a variable to the core_config_data table using an \Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config object:

```
$this->_resourceConfig->saveConfig(
                'mycompany/configuration/token',
                $token,
                'default',
                0
            );
```

then I clean the cache using \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Manager and Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config objects:

```
$this->_cacheManager->clean([CacheTypeConfig::TYPE_IDENTIFIER]);
```

Immediately, I redirect to another page that recalls the the same config variable, but it's null.

How do we make sure the cache cleaning finished before trying to read config data?

Comment: can you show your code, how your saving the value

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaram R, I use a resourceConfig object to save to the variable. This is my current understanding on how to do it. Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this was definitively solved, but after I upgraded to Magento 2.16, the issue was resolved. The coreConfig items are present between page loads now.